# m3u8 manifest continues downloading even with video paused

Tags: live-streaming, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I am using live-HLS with this type of manifest:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:8890
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:7
#EXTINF:6,
http://xyz1.ts
#EXTINF:4,
http://xyz2.ts
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:5,
https://abc1.ts
```

currently, when I paused video, browser continues doing manifest requests and .ts files continues downloading. How can I prevent it?

(I am simulating the live, in fact fragments are part of VOD files and server continuously update live manifest using these last).

Comment: What player are you using?

Comment: I am using only ```<video>``` tag in a simple html file

Comment: Then No, you can't control that.

Comment: I am using that only to test now, is it possible using some library to do it?

Comment: Yes, there’re are many html5 video players and frameworks.

Comment: please, give some suggestions to start. Thanks